# issue in upgrading hibernate-search v3.4.1.Final to hibernate-search-orm v5.9.3.Final

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

Earlier I was using hibernate-search v3.4.1.Final and now I'm upgrading my application so i have to use hibernate-search-orm v5.9.3.Final and accordingly I'm using hibernate-entitymanager v5.2.17.Final.
So after upgrading those dependencies in my code, i'm getting the following error: -

eclipse suggested error:-

```
The import org.apache.solr cannot be resolved
```

for code :-

```
import org.apache.solr.analysis.StandardTokenizerFactory;
```

I believe this can be resolved if I add "solr-core" dependency v3.1.0
but i'm not able to resolve this error:-

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Class<StandardTokenizerFactory> cannot be resolved to a type
    - StandardTokenizerFactory cannot be resolved to a type
UN_TOKENIZED cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

on line:-

```
@AnalyzerDef(tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), name = "en")
@Field(index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
```

Can anyone suggest which dependency can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a significant jump in versions. By the way, Hibernate Search 5.9 is already EOL. Consider looking at Hibernate Search 5.11 or 6.1 instead.

There are a lot of major changes in between your 3.4 and any 5.* versions. I'd suggest taking a look at the migration guides provided [here for versions up to 5](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-15249) and [here for versions 5+](https://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/).

```java
@Field(index = Index.UN_TOKENIZED)
```

`UN_TOKENIZED` means:

> Index the field's value without using an Analyzer, so it can be searched. As no analyzer is used the value will be stored as a single term. This is useful for unique Ids like product numbers.

So this means that it'll translate to:

```java
// for Hibernate Search 5+
// or in Hibernate Search 6+ look at the @KeywordField
@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)
```

---

> The import org.apache.solr cannot be resolved

Hibernate Search now does not rely on Solr anymore. It can work either with Lucene or with Elasticsearch [backends](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_backend).
Also, no need to include solr dependency. Instead, look for imports from `org.apache.lucene`.

---

> @AnalyzerDef(tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class), name = "en")

Using `@AnalyzerDef` is deprecated in Hibernate Search 5. See this [section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_analyzer) if you still want to use it, otherwise take a look at [Programmatic analyzer definition](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-analyzer-definition)

Comment: for "@Field(analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.YES)" i'm also using column annotation with length parameter ex:- "@Column(name = "search_key", length = 256)" will Analyze.NO will work?